# Iterate over dataframe to optimize project management

Tags: python, pandas, math, scipy, python-itertools

I have a pandas dataframe that contains the existing relationships between three ids: `manager_id`, `employee_id`, `project_id`. By changing which managers manage which employees, I'd need to find the situation where the lowest number of managers per project exists.

- One `manager_id` can have multiple `employee_ids`
- Each `employee_id` has a single `manager_id`
- Each `employee_id` can have one or many `project_ids`
- Each `project_id` can have one or many `employee_id`

The only further condition is that each manager can take a specific maximum number of employees (10% more than they currently have).

My initial thought was to take a cartesian product between all the projects and managers, to find all the possible combinations; limit the outcome to scenarios that fit the maximums; then find the scenario with the lowest number of rows. Tried to achieve that with this:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations

relationship_df = pd.DataFrame({'manager_id':  [1,1,2,2,2,2],
                            'employee_id': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                            'project_id':  [1,2,1,2,None,None],}
                          )

# Create  a dictionary with all the projects and number of employees working on them
project_df = relationship_df.groupby('project_id')['employee_id'].count()
project_df = project_df.sort_values(ascending = False)
project_dict = project_df.to_dict()

# Create a dictionary with all the managers and number of employees working for them
manager_df = relationship_df.groupby('manager_id')['employee_id'].count()
manager_df = manager_df.sort_values(ascending = False)
manager_dict = manager_df.to_dict()

# Create all the possible permutation orders for the projects:
project_perms = list(permutations(project_dict))

# For each possible permutation, assign the project to the manager until their team is full:
for perm_num, perm in enumerate(project_perms):
    for manager, team_size in manager_dict.items():
        new_teams = {}
        for project in perm:
            project_size = project_dict[project]
            if sum(new_teams.values()) <= 1.1 * team_size:
                new_teams[project] = project_size
```

Is there a better way to achieve this or a specific package/algorithm I should use?

Comment: What do you mean by "fewest number of relations"? Can you provide some example inputs and an expected output?

Comment: Edited the question with some sample data. I want the lowest number of managers per project.